# BPM BonitaSoft Community Edition 6.2.1 with SQL Server 2005 - Installation Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, business-process-management

We're trying to install community edition of Bonita Soft 6.2.1, and we've created the BONITA and JORNAL databases on MS SQL SERVER 2005. We enabled XA Transaction support like the instructions said and we've tried both JDBC4 and jDTC driver. In the log errors, I see that it tries to create a table with a BOOLEAN data type field. But SQLServer has no boolean datatype, is that right ?

Does anybody has a clue ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

open file setenv.sh on tomcat/bin folder.
Edit this line: DB_OPTS="-Dsysprop.bonita.db.vendor=your db vendor", then restart server and try again.
:)

Comment: Tried it and now I can see it created the tables. Thank you!